# select the key and the value without the equal using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hava a string like this:

```
"let key1=value1; let key2=value2;"
```

I want to select the key and value as groups using regex, I've tried using look around.

`/(\w+)(?=\=)(\w+);/g`

but it doesn't work with me, any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe: `let\s(\w+)=(\w+);` where you can get group 1 as keys and group2 as values?

Comment: Just consume it, `/(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+);/g`. However, you should not use regex to parse JS code. There are parsers for it.

Comment: @JvdV nope it will select the equal, also will select the white spaces

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it will select the equal which I don't want to, am trying to edit a string code before running it on the virtual machine.

Comment: It won't select it. It will match it. But you will be able to get the captured substrings.

Comment: `Array.from("let key1=value1; let key2=value2;".matchAll(/(\w+)\s*=\s*(\w+)/g), x => [x[1], x[2]])`

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should do the trick: `(let (\w+) ?= ?(\w+);?)+`.
Each `let` statement will be a match where the key will be the group 2 and the value the group 3.

Answer (score 0):

The `(?=\=)` expression part is a lookahead, a zero-width assertion, it does not consume text but requires it to be present on the right. When you say `(?=\=)(\w+)` you want `\w+` pattern to start matching on `=`. As `\w` does not match `=`, your regex always fails.

Use

```
/(\w+)=(\w+);/g
```

JavaScript (borrowed from [How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493)):

```js
var myString = "let key1=value1; let key2=value2;";
var myRegexp = /(\w+)=(\w+);/g;
match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
while (match != null) {
  console.log(match[1] + "," + match[2]);
  match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

To be more specific, we could use `(\w+) ?= ?(\w+);?+`